# MYSQL and LabVIEW

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 27 columns and 300,000 rows of data, out of which 8 columns are filled with data 0 or 1 or null. Using LabVIEW I get the total count of each of these columns using the following query:

```
select  
 d_1_result, 
 d_2_value_1_result,
 de_2_value_2_result,
 d_3_result,
 d_4_value_1_result,
 d_4_value_2_result,
 d_5_result
 from Table_name_vp
 where  ( insp_time between 
 "15-02-02 06:00:00" and "15-02-02 23:59:59" or  
 inspection_time between "15-02-03 00:00:00" and "15-02-03 06:00:00")  
 and partname = "AbvQuene";
```

This query runs for the number of days the user input, for example 120 days.
I found that total time taken by the query is 8 secs which not good.
I want to reduce the time to 8 millisecs.
I have also changed the engine to Myisam.
Any suggestions to reduce the time consumed by the query. (LabVIEW Processing is not taking time)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data, and how many rows out of the 300,000 are actually selected by your `WHERE` clause.  Obviously if all 300,000 are included, the whole table will need to be read.  If it's a smaller number of rows, an index on `insp_time` or `inspection_time` (is this just a typo, are these actually the same field?) and/or `partname` might help.  The exact index will depend on your data.

Answer (score 0):

Update 2:

I can't see any reason for you wouldn't be able to load your whole DB into memory because it should be less than 60MB. Do you agree with this?

Please post your answer and the answer the following questions (you can edit a question after you have asked it - that's easier than commenting).

Next steps:

1. I should have mentioned this before, that before you run a query in LabVIEW I would always test it first using your DB admin tool (e.g. MySql Workbench). Please post whether that worked or not.
2. Post your LabVIEW code.
3. You can try running your query with less than 300K rows - say 50K and see how much your memory increases. If there's some limitation on how many rows you can query at one time than you can break your giant query into smaller ones pretty easily and then just add up the results sets. I can post an example if needed.

Update:
It sounds like there's something wrong with your schema.

For example, if you had 27 columns of double's and datetimes ( both are 8 bytes each) your total DB size would only be about 60MB (300K * 27 * 8 / 1048576).

Please post your schema for further help (you can use SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename).

---

8 millisecs is an extremely low time - I assume that's being driven by some type of hardware timing issue? If not please explain that requirement as a typical user requirement is around 1 second.

To get the response time that low you will need to do the following:

1. Query the DB at the start of your app and load all 300,000 rows into memory (e.g. a LabVIEW array)
2. Update the array with new values (e.g. array append)
3. Run the "query" against he array (e.g. using a for loop with a case select)
4. On a separate thread (i.e. LabVIEW "loop") insert the new records into to the database or do it write before the app closes

This approach assumes that only one instance of the app is running at a time because synchronizing database changes across multiple instances will be very hard with that timing requirement.

Comment: I addressed that above - please post your schema info.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `gtron_component_info` 
(
   `part_count` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  
 `system_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   
`packaging_level_1_no` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   
`location` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  
 `part_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
   
`inspection_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   
`Total_Count` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  
 `inspection_result` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  
 `defect_1_value_1` float(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  
 `defect_1_result` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: `defect_2_value_1` float(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
   
`defect_2_value_1_result` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 
`defect_2_value_2` float(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
 
`defect_2_value_2_result` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
 
`defect_2_result` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  
 `defect_3_value_1` float(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
   
`defect_3_result` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   
`defect_4_value_1` float(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
   
`defect_4_value_1_result` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   
`defect_4_value_2` float(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
   
`defect_4_value_2_result` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   
`defect_4_result` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: `defect_5_value_1` float(8,4) DEFAULT NULL,
   
`defect_5_result` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
   
KEY `defect_1_result` (`defect_1_result`),
   
KEY `defect_2_value_1_result` (`defect_2_value_1_result`),
  
 KEY `defect_2_value_2_result` (`defect_2_value_2_result`),
  
 KEY `defect_2_result` (`defect_2_result`),
  
 KEY `defect_3_result` (`defect_3_result`),
   
KEY `defect_4_value_1_result` (`defect_4_value_1_result`),
  
 KEY `defect_4_value_2_result` (`defect_4_value_2_result`),
   
KEY `defect_4_result` (`defect_4_result`),
  
 KEY `defect_5_result` (`defect_5_result`),

Comment: KEY `inspection_time` (`inspection_time`),
   

KEY `inspection_result` (`inspection_result`)
 ) 
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
 /*!50100 
PARTITION BY RANGE (to_days(inspection_time))
(PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN ("15-02-01") ENGINE = MyISAM,
  
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN ("15-03-01") ENGINE = MyISAM,
  
PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN ("15-04-01") ENGINE = MyISAM,
 
 PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN ("15-05-01") ENGINE = MyISAM,
 
 PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN ("15-06-01") ENGINE = MyISAM,
 
 PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN ("15-07-01") ENGINE = MyISAM,

Comment: PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN ("15-07-01") ENGINE = MyISAM,
PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN ("15-08-01") ENGINE = MyISAM,
PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN ("15-09-01")NGINE = MyISAM,
 
 PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN ("15-10-01") ENGINE = MyISAM,
 
 PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN ("15-11-01") ENGINE = MyISAM,
 
 PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = MyISAM)

Comment: I've responded above with more questions.